# NTLM/Kerberos works on browser but not with my app with Alamofire

Tags: swift, authentication, alamofire, kerberos, ntlm

Since an authentication change in our server, I have to add kerberos authent in our ios app. I tried everything found on internet but nothing works.

Here is my code

```
    private static let sessionManager: Session = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 25
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 25
        configuration.urlCredentialStorage = nil

        let retrier = RetryPolicy()
        
        return Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: retrier)
    }()
    
    private static func performRequest<T: Decodable>(email: String = email ?? "",
                                                     password: String = password ?? "",
                                                     route: APIRouter,
                                                     decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
                                                     completion: @escaping (AFResult<T>) -> Void) {
        let credential = URLCredential(user: email, password: password, persistence: .permanent)

        sessionManager.request(route)
            .authenticate(with: credential)
            .responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { completion($0.result) }
    }
```

and calling `performRequest` with the good info lead to a bad return.

While, if I go to the route on Safari et connect with the good identifiers, I receive the good json.
I saw few things with challenge, but it seems to be for older version of alamofire.

So why it's works fine on browser and not on my app? I understand people working for Safari a very good developers, but still.

Thanks

Comment: You need to investigate the `URLCredential` you're creating (do you actually pass a username and password? Your code can hide bugs here.) as well as the traffic that goes over the network. To do that you can use a web proxy tool or network analyzer like Wireshark.

Comment: Finally, it seems that the backend is not working as expected.